# Protection against unauthorized redeployment of PHP applications

Tags: php, copy-protection

I was wondering what options do we have? PHP is open, I know. But what if I want to bind my work to one server, so that a client could not resell / steal my work. I run my own server, so I can provide a remote authorization mechanism, but I'm not yet aware of any.

What options do we have? Zend is paid and useless because of DeZender; ditto ionCube. So, what are our protection options?

Comment: There is nothing much you could do other than hosting your client websites or application on your server if you dont use some sort of encoders

Comment: Strong legal contracts, and a willingness to sic the lawyers on violators

Comment: "because of DeZender," at 5$ a file I don't think that DeZender is that affordable

Comment: Thanks all. DeZender is very affordable if illegally acquired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No app is safe if it is on customer's premises, whatever the technology is. So the only way to keep is safe is just to self-host it... The harder you try, the more bugs and performance losses you introduce, and the result is always uncertain.

Ioncube and zend are options which help you to discourage reverse engineering and access to code, but they won't stop a determined user.

But remember that the tecnical mean is always just a part of the game. The other part is a properly written and signed EULA or agreement with your customer.